# Idris case/induction tactics

Tags: algebraic-data-types, idris, formal-verification

They were implemented in Idris 0.9.14 and I successfully used `induction` for some proofs. However, they work only for some library types; while, for example, `Vect` supports them, nearly-isomorphic `All` does not:

```
-Main.h2> induction ys1 INTERNAL ERROR: induction needs an eliminator for Data.Vect.Quantifiers.All
This is probably a bug, or a missing error message.
Please consider reporting at https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues
```

Unfortunately there isn't plenty of language documentation, and I couldn't find how to implement elimination/case analysis for custom types. Digging into Prelude, I found the `%elim` modifier, but it didn't help. Could anybody give an example for, say, the aforementioned `All`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `induction` tactic can only be used on types that were declared with `%elim`.  Some people feel that Idris should be automatically generating eliminators whenever possible, but there would appear to be some technical difficulties with that.

> Could anybody give an example for, say, the aforementioned All?

As far as I can tell, there should be no problem adding `%elim` to the definition of `All` (just edit the file `Quantifiers.idr` and recompile idris).  You may want to submit a pull request on Github.

Comment: Thanks! When I tried to add %elim (to my custom type) at first, it didn't work, but now it does. Probably had to update or recompile something.